# Same environment with different names

Tags: environments

A new environment can be made with:

```
\newenvironment{name}[1]{stuff at the beginning}{stuff at the end}
```

In the document the environment can be created with:

```
\begin{name} different stuff \end{name}
```

Now I want to call the same environment with different names. My solution is:

```
\newenvironment{name1}[1]{stuff1}{stuff2}
\newenvironment{name2}[1]{stuff1}{stuff2}
...
\newenvironment{nameN}[1]{stuff1}{stuff2}
```

This is pretty dirty and makes my code confusing. Do you know a better solution? Something like this would be great:

```
\newenvironment{name1, name2,  ... , nameN}[1]{stuff1}{stuff2}
```

Comment: why use a different name not an argument?  `\begin{name2}`  looks weird, why not have `\begin{name}[type=2]...`  or some other argument form to distinguish them?

Comment: @campa I don't think, that this is what I mean.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm working on Templates, that produce differen styled PDFs. But a TeX code with one template should work with all other templates. When doing math i often use \begin{theorem} etc. but when I do Pen and Paper I use \begin{MonsterBox} etc. The point is, that the TeX for math should work with Pen and Paper, too

Comment: why change the environment name, the latex model would normally be you use the same name with different definitions

Comment: I still don't understand.  What makes `name1` different from `name2`?  From what you've shown, they would have the same output.  How is `theorem` different from `MonsterBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The code below defines a new command `\NewEnvironments` that will define multiple copies of an environment using a comma separated list of names for the environments. The syntax is:

```
\NewEnvironments[#args]{comma separated list of names}{env beginning}{env end}
```

So the syntax is similar to `\newenvironment` except that the optional argument for the number of arguments must be first. For example, you can define a series of environments, `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, `name4`, that accept one argument using:

```
\NewEnvironments[1]{name1,name2,name3,name4}
  {\textbf{Environment with one arg: ##1}\newline\itshape}% begin
  {\newline\textbf{End of 1 environment}\par}             % end
```

Note the use of `##1`, rather than `#1`, for the parameter inside the environment definition. Of course, since all of these environments are the name you could only use `name1`. On the other hand, the code supports defining environments that depend on their name such as:

```
\NewEnvironments[1]{name1,name2,name3,name4}
  {\textbf{Environment #1 with one arg: ##1}\newline\itshape}% begin
  {\newline\textbf{End of 1 environment}\par}                % end
```

Here is the MWE showing how to use the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

% usage: \NewEnvironments[#args]{comma separated list of names}{env beginning}{env end}
\newcommand\NewEnvironments[4][0]{%
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\newenvironment{##1}[#1]{#3}{#4}}
    \docsvlist{#2}
}

% examples

% environments with no arguments
\NewEnvironments{none1,none2,none3,none4}
    {\textbf{Environment with no args}\newline\itshape}% begin
    {\newline\textbf{End of 0 environment}\par}        % end

% environments with one arguments
\NewEnvironments[1]{name1,name2,name3,name4}
    {\textbf{Environment with one arg: ##1}\newline\itshape} %  begin
    {\newline\textbf{End of 1 environment}\par}              % end

\begin{document}

  \begin{none1}stuff\end{none1}
  \begin{none2}stuff\end{none2}
  \begin{none1}stuff\end{none1}
  \begin{none3}stuff\end{none3}
  \begin{none4}stuff\end{none4}
  \begin{none1}stuff\end{none1}

  \begin{name1}{one}stuff\end{name1}
  \begin{name2}{two}stuff\end{name2}
  \begin{name1}{three}stuff\end{name1}
  \begin{name3}{four}stuff\end{name3}
  \begin{name4}{five}stuff\end{name4}
  \begin{name1}{six}stuff\end{name1}

\end{document}
```

**Original answer**

It seems unusual to me that the name environments are all exactly the same, but I accept that there may be good reasons for this. One way to do what you want without duplicating code is to have a "template" environment that contains the main code and then have the other environments use this. That is, a structure like:

```
\newenvironment{nametemplate}[1]{stuff1}{stuff2}
\newenvironment{name1}[1]{\nametemplate{#1}...}{...\endnametemplate}
\newenvironment{name2}[1]{\nametemplate{#1}...}{...\endnametemplate}
...
```

The dots `...` inside the `\newenvironment` definitions allow you to include extra code if you want but, as described in the OP, these dots should be omitted.

Comment: This is a bit better, but still needs a lot of code. So there is no better way in doing that? E.g. using lists and for-loops, so that a list contains all the names, and the for-loop makes the newenvironment defines (for-loop as a sujective function)?

Comment: @Titanlord See my update

Comment: This is a pretty good answer! Thank you very much!